# help Ajax slideUp / show in mvc3 project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to use some ajax in a project but I can't seem to get it working, just to try it out I have made a button in one of my views with which I want to hide (slideUp) the whole body

I have tried this code inside my view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js")></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" >$("button#hideAll").click(function ()
         {
            if ($("body").is(":hidden")) {
                  $("body").show("slow");
            } else {
                  $("body").slideUp();
                   }
             });{
 </script>
```

[image: this is the viewpage, at the top is the hide all button which I want to use]

ps: if you have any other remarks on the layout etc, I'd be glad to hear them too.

EDIT:
This is some more of the html code btw:

```
<p id="uitlegToonStudenten">Hieronder ziet u 2 lijsten van studenten. U kan één of meerdere studenten selecteren om hen naar de andere lijst van studenten te verplaatsen.</p>
<hr>

<button id="hideAll">hide All!</button>
```

EDIT:
update on code (still doesn't work:)

```
<button id="hideAll">hide All!</button>
<div id="bodyFake">

<p id="uitlegToonStudenten">Hieronder ziet u 2 lijsten van studenten. U kan één of meerdere studenten selecteren om hen naar de andere lijst van studenten te verplaatsen.</p>
<hr>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js") type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" >
  $(function () {
         $("button#hideAll").click(function () {
             if ($("div#bodyFake").is(":hidden")) {
                 $("div#bodyFake").slideDown();
             } else {
                 $("div#bodyFake").slideUp();
             }
         });
     });
 </script>
```

As you can see I've put the everyting in a 'fake' body div and put the button above (there is more code and I close the div at the end)
***EDIT2:***
this was the 'big mistake':

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your code in `$(function(){..}` that way it will ensure that the element is available before it tries to access it. Also to show the element you can use `slideDown` which is the opposite of `slideUp`. There is an extra opening brace in your code remove it. You can try this.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PbeRa/)**

```
  $(function () {
     $("#hideAll").click(function () {

         if ($("div#bodyFake").is(":hidden")) {
             $("div#bodyFake").slideDown();
         } else {
             $("div#bodyFake").slideUp();
         }
     });
  });
```

Comment: and this has to come inbetween the <script type="text/javascript"> tags, right?

edit: tried it and doesn't work yet, But I'll keep searching, thanks!

Comment: Can you post your markup? Because you are trying to hide `body` it will hide the button also. How will you show it again? Did you put the button outside `body`?

Comment: hmm, right! I'll try hiding a div with a seperate ID instead (everything is in body, it is rendered in a master page)

Comment: Keep all the body content in a main `div` and the button outside of this div, change your code accordingly you should be good

Comment: Ok, I have tried this and it still does not work.., I'll edit my newest code in the question

Comment: You are missing the closing tag of `div` with id bodyFake.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer, in the fiddle your had some typo. The ids are case sensitive. Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/PbeRa/

Comment: I actually Copy Pasted it and it Still does not work :s I am using Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox to test. Do I maybe need to add a reference to jquery?

Comment: Did you see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PbeRa/ ? I have modified it and it is working fine.

Comment: Yes, I have copied the code from the jfiddle, that's why I find it strange that it doesn't work in my project.

Comment: it works now! <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
added this code